# getting column value from database onListitemClick

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, listview, cursor

I am trying to get the value of one row from column "threadid" from database onListItemClick, but on every list item I click I get the value of previous row, and when I click the first item of the list my app crashes, I don't know what's the problem, Please help me catch my problem.My code is:

```
int threadid= datasource.getthreadid(id);
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                          String.valueOf(threadid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 public int getthreadid(long id)
  {
      int threadid = 0;
      String ide=String.valueOf(id);
      String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID 
                + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME 
                + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + ide;
      Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
     // cursor.moveToFirst();
     // cursor.moveToPosition(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
    cursor.moveToFirst();
          threadid = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("threadid"));


      cursor.close();
    return threadid;      
  }
```

When my app crashes its logcat is:

```
09-13 15:58:57.465: V/Provider/Setting(7403): from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
09-13 15:58:57.466: D/AndroidRuntime(7403): Shutting down VM
09-13 15:58:57.466: W/dalvikvm(7403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41373908)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:433)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at soft.b.peopleassist.DataSource.getthreadid(DataSource.java:41)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at soft.b.peopleassist.Receive.onListItemClick(Receive.java:136)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1114)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2946)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3722)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
09-13 15:58:57.469: E/AndroidRuntime(7403):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is this code before public int getthreadid(long id)? Can you post the code of onListItemClick?

Comment: getthreadid is the function in one class and the other is code in the other class from where I am calling this function.I want to get the value of threadid on the value of id ,id is unique.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to see where you're getting this id parameter from in the line int threadid= datasource.getthreadid(id);

Comment: this id is actually the id we get onListitemClick method, I am using that id to get the value of threadid column in that row.

Comment: So do your id's in the database start with zero? It seems that they may actually start with 1...

Comment: my id column is auto increment column and I starts with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be probably better if you didn't rely on the position in the list being equal to the id from the database. Maybe you can store the database id in the object you use to populate the list and then get this object back in onClick and use its id.